# Extra "//" in Bibtex Entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am using [GBT7714](https://ctan.org/pkg/gbt7714?lang=en) bibliography style for my document. For the following key:

```
@inProceedings{my_key,
  author       = "author",
  title        = "title",
  booktitle    = "booktitle",
  year         = "year",
  editor       = "editor",
  volume       = "volume",
  number       = "number",
  series       = "series",
  pages        = "pages",
  address      = "address",
  publisher    = "publisher",
  note         = "note",
}
```

I get the following result:

```
AUTHOR.title[C]//EDITOR. series:  volume    booktitle.   address:  publisher,  year:pages.
```

I dont know why **"//"** is getting printed. How to remove this?

Comment: because it is not `\\\`.

Comment: @Oni would you please like to elaborate it. As a beginner, I am not sure if I quite get it

Comment: You presumably have a good reason for employing this particular bib style. If that's the case, you presumably would be well advised *not* to modify anything about the bib style file.

Comment: @Mico yes, this bib style is the requirement for the thesis. However, if I go to the documentation check the documentation of this bib format, "//" is nowhere to be found.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks but I'm using overleaf.com and can't see the code.

Comment: You can see the code at the link you gave (that's what I did)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The double slash mark is identical to "in:" which indicates this piece of work is extracted from the collection. It is specified in the [GB/T 7714—2015 standard](http://www.cessp.org.cn/uploads/1/file/public/201607/20160708142456_8mqgu0dpgk.pdf) (in Chinese) but is rarely used in other styles.

If you prefer the format "Title. In: book title", you may edit the line `#0 'in.booktitle :=` to `#1`.

Also, if you want to hide `\\`, set `slash.for.extraction :=` to `#0`.